# filter the updated value in redux whose i status id is deleted and displays those value whose status is ative

Tags: react-redux

i  am trying  to filter updated value from table and just  want to display those status id is 1  please find my attached code below

```
export const getCategories= () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        var response = await CategoriesService.invoke();
        const payload = response?.payload;
        const sortedList = sort(payload?.data, getComparator('asc', 'category_type'));
        dispatch(updateCatgories({...payload, data : sortedList,filerActiveList }));
    } catch (error) {
        logger.error('Error getting categories Service from API', error);
    }
  };
};
const List = response.payload.data;
const filerActiveList =()=>{
  return List.fliter((item)=>item.status_id=="1");

}
```

Comment: I think you should filter on the server but if you want to fetch all data and filter on the client you should use a [parameterized selector](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors).

Comment: can you do modification in my code and send